# Is it possible to pass an expression containing lt or gt operators as a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

I thought the following programm is well-formed:

```
#include <iostream>

template <bool>
void foo(){ };

int a = 4;
int b = 5;
int main(){ foo<a<b>(); }
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e05c636ebe48eaf3)

The reason I was thinking that way was (`N4296::14.2/3 [temp.names]`):

> After name lookup (3.4) finds that a name is a `template-name` or that
>   an `operator-function-id` or a `literal operator-id` refers to a set of
>   overloaded functions any member of which is a function template, if
>   this is followed by a `<`, the `<` is always taken as the delimiter of a
>   `template-argument-list` and never as the less-than operator. When
>   parsing a `template-argument-list`, the first non-nested `>` is taken
>   as the ending delimiter rather than a greater-than operator.

In that example we can see that the first `<` in the `foo<a<b>()` expression is being treated as a start point of the template arguments. The template arguments is up to the first `>`, so `a<b` should be considered as just an argument. But it wasn't, what's wrong?

Comment: `bool n=(a<b); foo<n>();`?

Comment: @ForceBru The question wasn't about how to fix the code to be worked, but about understanding why one wasn't working.

Comment: Or just `foo<(a<b)>();`, but I think OP is asking about the rules under which the syntax he attempted is not permissible. This has to do with the parsing of stuff like `vector<vector<int>>`, but the precise rules I don't know off hand.

Comment: @Wintermute http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9bcbdb4c7354766d

Comment: Why do you think `a<b` is a compile-time constant expression?

Comment: Ah. Yes, as multiple people have noticed by now, those simply are not compile time constants and therefore cannot be used as template arguments. I didn't notice that the first time.

Comment: Also, the clang error message in the coliru demo correctly underlines `foo<a<b>` as the function name, so the basic parse is working as expected; `a<b` is the (invalid) template argument.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this is possible, as long as the expression is a compile-time constant expression.

All you need to do is to make your `int` a `constexpr`. You may want to add parentheses around your expression for the human readers of your code (compiler will have no problem parsing `foo<a<b>` correctly, while humans would think there's a missing `>` at the end):

```
constexpr int a = 4;
constexpr int b = 5;
int main(){ foo<(a<b)>(); return 0;}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/4grxGp)

Answer (score 2):

`a<b` is a compile time constant only if both `a` and `b` are compile time constants.

This works for me:

```
#include <iostream>

template <bool>
void foo(){ };

const int a = 4;
const int b = 5;
int main(){ foo<a<b>();}
```